# WP Courseware & ACF - create overview of available courses

Tags: wordpress, advanced-custom-fields, custom-fields

I'm using WP Courseware and I would like to create a page with all available courses.

The problem is:
- Courses aren't really pages with fields that I can use. It's not a CPT either from what I can tell. I can't add custom fields to this section since ACF isn't able to read anything from it.

I found this question that seems like it does what I need: [A complicated query combining a WP Courseware function, ACF repeater fields and a meta_query looking for a particular template file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43287702/a-complicated-query-combining-a-wp-courseware-function-acf-repeater-fields-and/)

EXCEPT I'm not sure how she handled the repeater field. Any ideas? 
SO my question is, how did she create the repeater field and added a page ID to that field?

- If I can find out how she did this, I will probably be able to make a separate page with all the modules connected to the course.

I have used the same code from the article since my goal is exactly the same. My problem is that I don't know how to use ACF in this case (have used ACF before but not for something like this).

```
$user = wp_get_current_user();
                $user_id = $user->ID;
                $user_course_list = WPCW_users_getUserCourseList($user_id);
                $course_association_arr = get_field('course_association', 'option');
                // Loop through user's courses
                foreach ( $user_course_list as $user_course ) : 
                    $course_id = $user_course->course_id;
                    $course_title = $user_course->course_title;
                    // Loop through the ACF course ID/page associations
                    foreach ( $course_association_arr as $course_association ) :
                        $assoc_course_id = $course_association['wp_courseware_id'];
                        if ( $course_id == $assoc_course_id ) :
                            // Loop through the ACF associated pages
                            foreach ( $course_association['associated_pages'] as $associated_page ) :
                                $page_id = $associated_page->ID;
                                $page_url = $associated_page->guid;
                                $args = array(
                                    'post_type' => 'page',
                                    'page_id' => $page_id,
                                    'meta_query' => array(
                                        array(
                                            'key' => '_wp_page_template',
                                            'value' => 'page-course-home.php',
                                        ),
                                    )
                                );
                                $course_assoc_pages = new WP_Query( $args );
                                if( $course_assoc_pages->have_posts() ) :
                                    while ( $course_assoc_pages->have_posts() ) : $course_assoc_pages->the_post();
                                        echo '<li><a href="' . $page_url . '">'. $course_title . '</a></li>';
                                    endwhile;
                                endif;
                                wp_reset_query();
                            endforeach;
                        endif;
                    endforeach;
                endforeach;
```

Comment: It all starts reading the relevant documentation to understand how to iterate through the repeater fields: [ACF | Repeater](https://www.advancedcustomfields.com/resources/repeater/)

Comment: That's not an answer to my question. 
I know how the repeater works, I'm just not sure how to create an option page with the repeater and have the field linked to the ID from the course. 

I tried and it's not outputting anything.

Comment: It's better to show your code, otherwise everything is mostly speculative from an outsider...

Comment: The code is the same as linked in the article, because the goal is the same. I'm not sure what to do with ACF, how to add the fields.